# Validate two form with one submit button using jquery in JSP Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#one").validate({  // initialize form validation on form 1
        // rules & other options
        messages: {
            input1: "salam"
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            element.focus(function () {
                $("#msg_required").html(error);
            }).blur(function () {
                $("#msg_required").html('');
            });
        }
    });
    $("form#two").validate({ // initialize form validation on form 2
        // rules & other options,
        messages: {
            input2: "bah"
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            element.focus(function () {
                $("#msg_required").html(error);
            }).blur(function () {
                $("#msg_required").html('');
            }); // default error placement
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            if ($("form#one").valid()) {  // test to see if form 1 is valid
                $( "form#two" ).submit();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- FORM #1: -->
<br/>
<form action="#" id="one">
    <input type="text" name="input1" class="required" />
</form>

<!-- FORM #2: -->
<br/>
<form action="#" id="two">
    <input type="text" name="input2" class="required" />
    <br />
    <span dir="rtl" id="msg_required" class="msg_required"></span>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I submit form two, the error message from form one is not shown.
 (`includes jQuery_Validation_Plugin_1.9.0.js and jquery-1.9.1.js`)

Comment: I dont get why you use two `form` for only two text inputs. You should also look for an [updated jQuery Validation plugin (1.15.0)](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and an [updated jQuery library (1.12.4)](http://jquery.com/download/) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Form 1 error can't show up because its not submitted when the submit button is clicked.You should run your code like this:

```js
$("#submit_btn").on('click' function (){
    //run your from submission here
})
```

```html
    <br/>
    <form action="#" id="one">
        <input type="text" name="input1" class="required" />
    </form>

    <!-- FORM #2: -->
    <br/>
    <form action="#" id="two">
        <input type="text" name="input2" class="required" />
        <br />
        <span dir="rtl" id="msg_required" class="msg_required"></span>
        <br /><br />
    </form>

    <!--place the submit button here-->
    <button id="submit_btn">submit</button>
```

Now to create a function to submit the 2 forms on clicking the button